# Proven and Scalable Comet Server

Tags: streaming, ajax

What is the most proven, scalable comet server solution out there that can handle up to 100.000 real-life connections per node using HTTP streaming (not long-poll)? It must be a free, preferably open-source project.

We've already tried Meteor (Perl), with no success. Meteor was able to scale just up to 20.000 connections per node.

We are looking right now at these options: APE (C++), Orbited (Python), Grizzly (Glassfish), Cometd (Jetty).

Any big success stories with any of these?

Answer (score 3):

I am the maintainer of Meteor.  While we don't have any official figures on expected load capacity, 20,000 per node is not unreasonable.  There are certainly comet solutions that can handle more clients.  All of the projects you've listed are viable options.  The only one I've tried personally aside from Meteor is Orbited, and found it worked well, but I've not load tested it.

Answer (score 3):

Erlang would be a good dynamic language for such a website. So you can have a look at [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) webserver.

[Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is an event-driven server framework for Java it may also be interesting. [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is a web framework based on Netty and it can be used with both Java and Scala.

Also see:

- [A Million-user Comet Application with Mochiweb, Part 1](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1)
- [Plurk Comet: Handling of 100.000+ open connections](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19456)